# How to access an element in a Perl array from a reference to an array of references

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I have the following Perl code:

```
package CustomerCredit;
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use 5.010;
use strict;

my $TransRef = @_; # This code comes from a sub within the package.
my ($Loop, $TransArrRef, $TransID);
for ($Loop = 0; $Loop < $$#TransRef; $Loop++)
{
   $TransArrRef = $$TransRef[$Loop]; # Gets a ref to an array.
   $TransID = $$TransArrRef[0];  # Try to get the first value in the array.
   # The above line generates a compile time syntax error.
   ...
}
```

$TransRef is a reference to an array of references to arrays.  I am trying to process each element in the array pointed to by $TransRef.  $TransArrRef should obtain a reference to an array.  I want to assign the first value within that array to $TransID.  But, this statement generates a compile syntax error.

I must be doing something wrong, but can not figure out what it is.  Can anyone help?

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error is coming from `$$#TransRef` which should be `$#$TransRef`. By misplacing the `#` you accidentally commented out the rest of the line leaving:

```
for ($Loop = 0; $Loop <= $$
{
   $TransArrRef = $$TransRef[$Loop];
   ...
}
```

`$$` is ok under `strict` as it gives you the process id leaving the compiler to fail further down.

Also, `$#$TransRef` gives you the last element in the array so you'd need `<=` rather than just `<`. Or use this Perl style loop:

```
for my $loop (0 .. $#$TransRef) {
    $TransID = $TransRef->[$loop]->[0];
    #   ...
}
```

Comment: there's also an error in `my $TransRef = @_;` which will assign a number (the number of elements in @_) to $TransRef

Answer (score 2):

```
my $arrays_ref = [ [1,2], [3,4] ];

for my $array_ref (@$arrays_ref) {

    printf "%s\n", $array_ref->[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` as well:

```
my @array = ('val1', 'val2', 'val3') ;
my $array_ref = \@array ;

print "array size is $#{$array_ref} \n" ;

foreach $elem (@$array_ref) {
   print "$elem \n"
}
```

Outputs:

```
array size is 2 
val1 
val2 
val3
```